# Update ListView background color when bluetooth get a new read

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to update each element every time an read comes from the Bluetooth, I found this

```
deviceListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

               if(getItem(position).startsWith("something"))
                {
                    // do something change color
                    row.setBackgroundColor (Color.GREEN); // some color
                }
                else
                {
                    // default state
                    row.setBackgroundColor (Color.RED); // default coloe
                }               
            return row;
        }
    };
```

It does updates the color, but here is the thing I have a list like this one

[image]

The list is loaded through a call to a server with Volley.

The things is that when the Bluetooth receive data, check if he id exists in the ListView and update the color to green.

I this even possible? Any thoughts on this can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what It was missing in the conditional to look if the id has being read.

I had to add `testArray.contains()` with that part it works as expected.

```
if(testArray.contains(getItem(position)))
    {
      row.setBackgroundColor (Color.GREEN); // some color
    }
    else
    {
      row.setBackgroundColor (Color.RED); // default coloe
    }
                   
    return row;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is update the item in `myList` and then call `deviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the list views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan, question what do you mean update the item in myList? Or how updating that it will change the color?

Comment: When you set up your ArrayAdapter you pass in a List named `myList`. That is passed by reference, so modifying, adding, or deleting any item in that list is also reflected in your adapter. Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` will force the view to refresh and `getView` will be called for each row again with the updated values. Your logic inside `getView` needs to determine the row color. Whatever that is depends on your needs.